# Note-taking (memo) app without a (reachable) length limitation

Tags: android, offline, text-editor, note-taking, plain-text

I am looking for a very simple, free and ad-free note-taking app for Android. UI-wise, I am happy with [S Memo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.widgetapp.diotek.smemo&hl=en) (the text part; I don't care much for the drawing feature), **except** that its text memos are limited to an abysmally low maximum length that I keep reaching all the time.

The main features I am looking for:

- supports Unicode-text notes of arbitrary length (or at least with a length limit that I'd only reach if I wrote a novel into a memo)
- supports any number of named memos
- easily allows me to export/access my memos (bonus points if it allows for some form of bulk/many-at-a-time export) as plain text files so I can grab them from the PC via USB

Also, the app must work without any network connection, as I am going to use it on a smartphone while underway.

Answer (score 1):

There are some notes apps saving their data directly to `.txt` files on the SD card – which saves you from taking care for your last bullet-point in terms of export, and you could have some app like *FolderSync* keeping your notes in sync with your PC directly.

One such app is **[Denkzettel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.silli.notizen)**, which is quite small: less than 800k app size. It supports text notes as well as lists (e.g. for shopping). You can even mark notes with different colors.

> Denkzettel is a notes-management for *.txt files. The advantage of this solution is the ability to synchronize his notes with any cloud service, especially their own cloud services like ownCloud, Nextcloud etc. can be used so easily.

[image: Denkzettel] [image: Denkzettel] [image: Denkzettel]
<sup>*Denkzettel* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.silli.notizen); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Not even asking for the `INTERNET` permission, it should perfectly fit your requirement of working offline. I'm not aware of any limitation concerning number or length of single "memos", and didn't check for full unicode compatibility. But as it looks like a good match and comes free, it's definitely worth a try.

---

What I've used for a long time was **[Note Everything](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.softxperience.android.noteeverything)**. This app additionally supports voice and photo notes, as well as hand-drawings, but again stores everything directly to your SD card. As *Denkzettel*, it doesn't even ask for the `INTERNET` permission.

For additional candidates, be welcome to take a look at my list of [notes app without cloud](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes#group_102)

Comment: I'm competely happy with *Denkzettel* now. Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: Unfortunately, Denkzettel 0.9.91 has stopped updating its list of notes now (meaning that newly created notes do not show up in the list (even though the files are there), and the existing ones are not ordered by last update (or by whatever sorting is configured in the settings)). I am investigating how to report this bug to the author. Until it is fixed, I have to (hopefully temporarily) revoke my above recommendation and acceptance for anyone who happens to stumble over this question in the meantime.